# REST backend framework for routing?

Tags: java, routing, rest, php, framework

I'm looking for a framework in Java or PHP to use it as backend for a mobile application. It should (if possible) implement REST services, geo functions for routing and CRUD services.

I found the Java framework GeoMajas, but I'm not quite sure to understand all it's functionnalities and for which type of project it should be used.

Any advices and ideas on which framework to use for this type of project ? Is GeoMajas a good one or isn't it designed for this case ?

Answer (score 3):

I think GeoMajas is a good choice. For routing purposes I want to introduce you [Graphhopper](http://graphhopper.com/). It's still a young project, but it's java, it's incredibly fast and there are ready to use applications to route either on a web server or on the mobile device itself based on openstreetmap data. So if you have no problems to use openstreetmap and want to route on a mobile device, you should take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using http://www.neo4j.org?  It's a Java based graph database, and comes ready with a algorithms suitable for routing http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graph-algo.html and a rest api http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api.html.  See a combination of the two at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank your for the reply! First time I hear about graph database. Really interesting but sounds complexe, and i don't have much time for this project. But I will concider this for futur projects!

Answer (score 0):

I don't known of any configurable rest-interface for routing, but [pgrouting](http://pgrouting.org/) is a popular open source solution. It runs inside the PostGIS-database. So you can use SQL-statements for routing. But you will have to program your own webservices on top of this.

ESRI has routing services on ArcGIS-online/server as well, but it is quite expensive (see: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline-content/index.html#//011q00000017000000).

Stuff like mapquest-directions is also an option, but then you can't use your own data. (http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/directions-ws)

Comment: I saw pgrouting also, and it looks pretty cool. Do you think a backend in PHP combined with a REST framework and pgrouting would be a good solution for a mobile application backend ?

Comment: There seem to be several examples of websites doing something like that (http://pgrouting.org/gallery.html) But i have personal experience with this product .